# File field fails to upload any files

Tags: 7, acquia-cloud

I've been having an issue with a file field that is not accepting any file uploads -- it ends up returning a 500 ISE on the specific field call (see image of the returned upload error). [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ05k.png)

The actual field itself is left over from a Database import of the site on an Acquia Cloud install. I know that it may be possible to re-create the field, but we stand the risk of losing existing records. Server configuration wise, it looks like the file directory is writable by httpd, so I don't see any issues there.

It doesn't help that the Acquia logs don't give anything useful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of the files, maybe they are to big. Check the max. file sizes on your server and in Drupal!.

PHP configuration check:

check the following parameters:

post_max_size

upload_max_filesize

If these values are to small, you have to change them on your server in your PHP configuration (for example php.ini)

Comment: I don't think it's going to be size or permissions related, those issues usually return a friendly drupal error message rather than resulting in a 500 error.

Comment: He has a point. We have pretty high settings for those already on Acquia Cloud. I'm wondering if they know something I don't. The files are typically under 2MB with a max size of at least 256 MB. Size isn't the issue.